# How to remove first column of auto generated counts from an R merged file?

Tags: r, merge, write.table

I have merged two files in R using `merge` and named it as 'mergedfile'. When I save the file as .txt on my desktop using `write.table("mergedfile", "~/Desktop/mergedfile.txt", sep = "\t")`, it adds an autogenerated column of row numbers in the file. How can I remove this column without loosing any original headers' name in the file when using `write.table` or another way to save the merged file on Desktop that doesn't include the first autogenerated column of row numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
write.table(mergedfile,file="~/Desktop/mergedfile.txt",sep='\t',row.names = F)
```

Comment: Worked, thank you :)